# jQuery ajax pass success into outside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem using jquery ajax. I have already a js player that works fine without ajax. I.E.

/jwplayer.js

```
window.onload = function () {

function etc etc etc

jwplayer('player').setup({
playlist: [{
file: video_url,
}],
width: "640",
height: "380",
autostart: "true",
stretching: "exactfit",
volume: "100",
});
}
```

PHP page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id='player'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var video_url = some_website_dot_com/file/.m3u8
</script>
```

This works just fine. But i cant add an ajax function to `var video_url`. This is the script that i'm trying to make it work

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var video_url = function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "some_website_dot_com/file/.m3u8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+m3u8)/);
        return result[1];
    }
});
}();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra `()` after the last `}`?

Comment: Yea, that's not possible.

Comment: @jgabb was the code that i found it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805306/jquery-return-ajax-result-into-outside-variable
However it doesnt work neither without `()`

Comment: It's an [iffe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return something from an inner function, why not just do this?

```
var video_url;
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "some_website_dot_com/file/.m3u8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+m3u8)/);
        video_url = result[1];
    }
});
```

Update: to get your player created and working when you get the url:

```
function setupVideo(data) {
    var result = data.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+m3u8)/);
    var video_url = result[1];
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: video_url,
        }],
        width: "640",
        height: "380",
        autostart: "true",
        stretching: "exactfit",
        volume: "100",
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "some_website_dot_com/file/.m3u8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: setupVideo
});
```

A good read on AJAX and specifically the A for asynchronous: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: Even i'm not sure if this is a proper way to use ajax, but i tried before, and it doesnt work.

Comment: It works for getting `video_url` but I guess you're not familiar with async? I update my answer.

Comment: I updated my question posting my jwplayer.js file exactly as it is.

Comment: But it's true, i'm not familiar with async

Comment: I have found a simple way:

`var page = $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "some_website_dot_com/file/.m3u8",
        dataType: "html",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
   return data;
 }
}).responseText;

var video = page.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+m3u8)/);
var video_url = video[1];`