# Populate dynamic arguments via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to initialize DropzoneJS with the dynamic url, which must be obtained via ajax call. How to do that **without `async: false`**? Result `url` will depend on `files` argument.

```
$('.class').dropzone({
    url: function(files) {
        var url;
        // ajax call here
        return url;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the ajax call and then intialize plugin in the success of the ajax when you have the data:

Something like:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/server',function(response){
    $('.class').dropzone({
        url: function(files) {            
            return response.url;
        }
     });
});
```

I don't know this plugin or the data structure....adjust accordingly

Comment: I can't because `url` will be calculated according to `files`.

Comment: Well without link to docs for plugin I can't help. remember there are 1000's of plugins out there and nobody knows all of them....and even when you do know them somewhat the api docs are critical

Comment: Also provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what is needed

Comment: For example I need different `url` for text files, media files, etc.

Comment: That isn't a very detailed explanation as regarding ajax. Also why can't you use a single upload point and let the server sort out whatever issues you have? What exactly is this ajax inside the plugin url function needed for?

Comment: OK, maybe I can obtain `url` in another way...
Please see [sending](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) attr. Inside it I need to populate formData with all this [data](https://github.com/hovel/django-s3direct/blob/master/s3direct/views.py#L62-L74) which will always be different.

Comment: See it for what? You are not being specific enough about anything to be able to help you. See [ask] and update question with enough details to work through whatever problem you have. I can't guess what you are trying to do or what constraints you have

Comment: I just need to return data from ajax call. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16805366/2694042) but without `async: false`. Can I do that?

Comment: Not simply because the plugin function won't wait for it and you should never use `async:false` and it is deprecated by browsers also