# Javascript - Scope of variables within and outside functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, scoping

I have an ajax request where i have a variable that i need to get outside the function. For some reason i am not able to get the values outside the function. For simplicity i am changing my function.

```
        var myEvents = "hi";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mywebsite.com/events',
            type: "post",
            success: function (response) {
                myEvents = 'hello';
            }
        });

        alert(myEvents); // shows "hi" but i want it to show "hello"
```

Comment: it's because alert() runs before your success callback

Comment: `... success: function (response) { myEvents = 'hello'; alert(myEvents);} ...`

Comment: @BenceFarkas yes you are right. But how can i get this variable in the main javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805306/jquery-return-ajax-result-into-outside-variable

Comment: @BenceFarkas thanks mate, i have been struggling with this for a few days but i knew there has to be a way to achieve this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` is called before the success callback you could enclode it in a function and call it in the callback:

```
var myEvents = "hi";
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mywebsite.com/events',
  type: "post",
  success: function(response) {
    myEvents = 'hello';
    func();
  }
});

function func() {
  alert(myEvents);
}
```

Comment: ok i understand it, but there is a lot of code and functions that are going to execute once the response is achieved. So, its not just a simple alert, there are lots of lines of code and functions. So I dont think it will be possible to bring all my code and functions inside the new function that you have created. There has to be a way to bring the scope the main js function.

Comment: It's not a scope problem it's a timing problem

Comment: You could use the answer to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests) to synchonously use the ajax call